# Display multiline error in Materials-UI TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I am trying to add an error string in `textfield` (from `materials UI`) and I want the error to display in multiple lines. Currently I have this in my `render` method:

```
<TextField
    floatingLabelText={'Input Field'}
    errorText={this.state.errorText}
    type='password'
    onChange={this.foo.bind(this)}
/>
```

and then the following function present inside the component:

```
foo(e) {
    let multilineText= `First line!
                      Second line!`;
    this.setState({
        errorText: multilineText,
    });
}
```

The issue I am having is that the error shows up in the same line. 
I tried using line breaks such as `\n` in the string as well but it still displays it in the same line. Is there any particular styling I should apply to have the text display in two separate lines?

Comment: Doesn't look like Material UI is designed to handle that. You could see if it handles rendering nodes, and pass in something like `<div>error1</div><div>error2</div>`

Comment: The approach of using `<div> Line one <br/> Line two </div>` does the job but I was wondering if I could achieve this by using the built in `errorText` field instead of using a separate div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning a `string` value you can assign any element, as per [DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field):

> errorText ------ node ---->   The error content to display.

Like this:

```
<TextField
    floatingLabelText={'Input Field'}
    errorText={error? <div>
                         <div>Hello</div>
                         <div>World</div>
                      </div>
                  : ''
              } 
    type='password'
    onChange={this.foo.bind(this)}
/>
```

Comment: This seems to do the job but it ends up displaying a red error line on the input field even when you dont have anything inside the `div`. Any way that can be fixed?

Comment: I looked at the doc and `inputStyle` and `errorStyle` don't seem to do the trick unfortunately.

Comment: you need to check the before showing the error, if error exist then show otherwise assign blank string to `errorText=''` will update the answer.

Comment: That works. I was initially passing the div directly into the `errorText` but passing in a variable `x` whose value changes from `x = ''` when there is no error and `x = <div> first line <br/> second line </div>` seems to do the job perfectly. Thanks!