# TextField Material UI long error go to the nextline

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, truncate

```
<TextField
     error="Super long message !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
     outlined
/>
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krvb6.png)

Currently the display is truncate. How to make it display multiple lines? I want to pass a dynamic string to error prop and need to auto detect the width to wrap the error message to go to the nextline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display multiline error in Materials-UI TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834271/display-multiline-error-in-materials-ui-textfield)

Comment: Please read the manual https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-fie